# Chrome intermittently puts content into overflow box with scrollbars

Tags: google-chrome, overflow

the site www.sterlingfoundations.com has an intermittent overflow problem with Google Chrome.  It sometimes takes three times of reloading to see the problem but it pushes all of the content below Navigation (currently id="wrapper") into a narrow column with scrollbar on the left margin (it happens on all the pages of the site).  The default.css gives "wrapper" an overflow: auto.  When removing the "default.css" file, the fonts go to default but the layout issue is solved.  So it has to do with the CSS overflow in "wrapper" I think.

One thing I noticed is the navigation bar looks like it squishes the longer phrases like "Private Foundations" and "Financial Professionals" and forces them to wrap to two lines when the problem occurs.  Not sure if that's related.  Any ideas?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you need overflow-y:auto on div#wrapper.